# Suggest joomla html editor extension/software

Tags: javascript, html, editor, tinymce, joomla1.5

I've started using Joomla 1.5 recently and am using the TinyMCE online WYSIWYG editor that comes with the package to edit articles. I tend to write direct html and javascript rather than use the WYSIWYG functions, I find that after the first time the changes are applied(page updated) most of your html becomes 4-5 separate big paragraphs. Its very hard to find stuff in there cause the content has no formatting -- eg:

```
<p><span id="psy_ass_span" class="pink_heading">Psychometric Assessment</span></p>
<div id="psy_ass_div" class="pink_box"><img class="img_right"     
src="templates/teamwork.jpg" border="0" />
<p><strong>Emporkommen</strong> uses <strong>Psychometric assessment</strong> as a tool     
in order to gain insight into a person’s personality and psychological thinking. It can 
help develop team spirit in t
<script src="plugins/editors/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js"   
type="text/javascript"></script>
he workplace and assess an individual’s priorities.</p>
```

Plus obviously there is no code highlighting in the editor so you can't figure out what is what. My question is, do you guys know of good(preferably non-commercial) extensions or other softwares or techniques that can make editing html code in Joomla 1.5 articles easier even after applying changes several times.

Comment: I think the best solution is if you want to focus on code and are willing to do use other editors like dreamweaver for the design, the best option is use No editor option. Ah! thankfully there's no TinyMCE putting <p> tags and what not as and when it feels like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try JCE - http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net.
It's a WYSIWYG Editor, but it has a great Code Editor with syntax highlighting and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/8723